# what is a storage type in mysql

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

Well, I'm reading 《High Performance MySQL》. It describes the differences between float and double. Now, I don't quite get what "As with integers, you're choosing only the storage type" means. Can anyone explain it in details. Thanks a lot.

> Floating-point types typically use less space than DECIMAL to store
>   the same range of values. A FLOAT column uses four bytes of storage.
>   DOUBLE consumes eight bytes and has greater precision and a larger
>   range of values. *As with integers, you’re choosing only the storage
>   type*; MySQL uses DOUBLE for its internal calculations on floating-
>   point types.

Comment: It means that, when you create an integer type field, for MySQL internal work it is like as you had used a DOUBLE. The only difference (in terms of visual work and data) is that you won't see the decimals. Is because of this that refers to the `storage type`. Or that's what I understand from the text you quoted.

Comment: This page shows the storage that mysql data types use when saved to physical storage. [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)
So for integer types it can be one, two, four or eight bytes.
Now, when those types are used in calculations by mysql, they are all converted to 'bigint' in memory which is 8 bytes long. This makes the actual processing more efficient as every integer is the same size.